# Tag Synonyms - how to create them

Tags: support, tags

There's an option for tag synonyms but I can't seem to figure out how to create the first one. For example it would be good to have

[msm](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/msm) == [multi-site-manager](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-site-manager) (both of these tags exist)

I'm sure that others will come up as the site evolves.

Comment: Very good idea. The obvious ones are...

EE = ExpressionEngine

CI = Code Igniter

DB = Database

CP = Control Panel

GV = Global Variable

SN = Snippet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think anyone's able to setup tag synonyms yet as it [requires a rep of 1250](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms).

Comment: Yip, and synonyms need to be voted on by the community to be approved as well. I guess we can work on them once we build up our rep.

Comment: You also need to have a score of at least 5 in the tag you want to add a synonym to

Comment: Moderators can... for now, that's us (the community team at SE). :)

Answer (score 3):

I set up a synonym to go from [msm](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/msm) to [multi-site-manager](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-site-manager) and merged them (so basically whatever questions were under [msm](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/msm) are now under [multi-site-manager](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-site-manager) instead).

While I was there, I also approved the following suggestions:

- [add-on-dev](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/add-on-dev) -> [add-on-development](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/add-on-development)
- <s>[store] -> [expresso-store]</s> (undid this one; see comments)

There are currently two remaining suggestions: [cp](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cp) -> [control-panel](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/control-panel) and [uri](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uri) -> [url](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url). You might want to kick off another discussion about whether or not those should be set up. With only two questions under [cp](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cp), it seems to make more sense to me to just retag those questions and let the tag age away. Same for [uri](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uri), except that it's also the more general form  of the term, so it might make more sense to make [url](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url) the synonym instead.

(Disclaimer: I say all this without having ever used ExpressionEngine, so I'm not sure if there are specific terminology issues at play here. Hence leaving the decisions to you folks.)

Comment: Does this mean that going forward whenever someone tags something store it will be labelled expresso-store?  That doesn't seem right, there are multiple store addons of which expresso-store is just one.

Comment: @UltraBob Hah. I was afraid of that. I looked at the existing questions in that tag and they all looked to be about the Expresso Store, so I made an assumption. I'm going to undo that synonym. You guys might want to keep an eye on the [store] tag. Sounds like it might get misused/become worthless.